# Find parameters of function $f$ such that $y$ is an oblique asymptote to $-\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification

> $\text{Let } f:(-\infty, -1) \cup [1, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}, \ f(x) = ax+b\sqrt{\frac{x^3-1}{x+1}}, \ a,b\in\mathbb{R}. \text{ Knowing that } \\ y=-x+1 \text{ is the oblique asymptote of } -\infty, \text{ find } a,b$

I've been struggling with solving this problem, and I cannot understand where my logic is faulty. If $y=-x+1$ is an oblique asymptote, then $$\lim_{x\to (-\infty)} \frac{f(x)}{x} = -1 \iff \lim_{x\to (-\infty)} a + b\sqrt{\frac{x^3-1}{x^3+x^2}} =-1\iff a+b=-1$$ Then $$\lim_{x\to (-\infty)} (f(x) -(a+b)x) = 1 \iff \lim_{x\to (-\infty)}(ax+b\sqrt{\frac{x^3-1}{x+1}}-ax-bx) =1 \iff \\[7ex] \lim_{x\to (-\infty)}b\cdot\frac{\frac{x^3-1}{x+1}-x^2}{\sqrt{\frac{x^3-1}{x+1}}+x} =1 \iff \lim_{x\to (-\infty)} b\cdot \frac{x^3-1-x^3-x^2}{(x+1)\cdot x\left(\sqrt{\frac{x-\frac{1}{x^2}}{x+1}}+1\right)} =1 \iff \\[12ex] \lim_{x\to (-\infty)}b\cdot \frac{-x^2-1}{x^2\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\cdot2} = 1\iff b =-2 \Rightarrow a=1$$

However, graphing this function on Desmos does not return a graph with an oblique asymptote that respects the requirements imposed by the problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the first line, you make the following assumption: $\frac{1}{x} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}}$ in order to pull the $x$ into the squareroot. However $x$ is negative (since $x\rightarrow -\infty$) so we actually have $\frac{1}{x} = -\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}}$